# error in Application icon

Tags: ios

I am getting an application icon error I have put all the icon images but I am still getting an error in it saying The app icon set named "App Icon" did not have any application content
What can be done to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can Generate App iOS and Android Icons of all sizes with a single click.

Personally I use https://makeappicon.com/ website to generate app icons.

Then go to xcassets file and place the icons in proper places.

[image]